# Passing dynamic Id to datatable elements

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add an edit button to each row of my jQuery datatable. I would like to add pass an id dynamically to the element 
Below is the code of my datable columns

```
"columns" : [ {
                "data" : "name"
            }, {
            "data" : null,
            defaultContent : '<a href="" id="dynamicId" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> '
        } ]
```

Below is my sample json data

```
{userId: 1, name:srk}
```

I tried passing data[userId] in the

```
<a href="" id="data[userId]" class="editor_edit">Edit</a>
```

Which is not passing id, I would like to pass the userId json value to the id attribute of the anchor element dynamically. I am using jQuery datatables version 1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to convert the json string to array object.

```
var data = '{"userId":"1", "name":"srk"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(obj, function(key,value)
{
    if(key==="userId")
     $('div').append('<a href="" id="' + value + '" class="editor_edit">Edit</a>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5uqoh3pk/

For a single item in json :

```
var data = '{"userId":"1", "name":"srk"}';
$('div').append('<a href="" id="' + ($.parseJSON(data))["userId"] + '" class="editor_edit">Edit</a>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5uqoh3pk/1/

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add jQuery to add the id in dynamically. Once it's outside of the script, it has no awareness of what's being passed.

```
$("a.editor_edit").attr("id", data[userId]);
```

You could do this for each item in your returned json object.

EDIT: the problem with doing it this way, is that it would find all instances of the anchor tag with the class of .editor_edit, and would add the latest user's id to that attribute.